# Django Page is not refreshing with new data sent from the server

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am new to Django so I will try to describe my scenario the best I can:

1. The user enter some String to search
2. The data is returned from the server and the data is populated in the table    accordingly
3. The user can then click on a button and data will appear in modal dialog
4. In the dialog box the user can change the search value and hit the search button to re search for the new value
5. a post request is sent to the server and the function is invoked in the views file
6. In the browser network under dev mode (F12) I can see that the response hold the new data but the page itself shows the old data

Does someone have an idea why this happens and how this can be resolved?

[image: bs modal box]

```
              var url = "{% url "ebanalyzer:search" %}";
          //window.location=url;
          $.post(url,{"query" : newValue,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},function (data,status) {
              //alert("data: " + data + "status: " +  status)
```

newValue param obtain the search field value

from urls file
        # /search
    url(r'^search/$', views.post_new, name='search'),

from views file
        @ensure_csrf_cookie
    def post_new(request):
    print(request.POST['query'])
    if request.POST["query"] != '':
        print("Rendering")
        return render(request, 'ebanalyzer/index.html', {"object_list":ebInfo.getSoldItems(request.POST["query"]) })

So just to emphasize the flow, user click on "paste" button --> ajax post is performed--> post_new is invoked (so far so good) --> response return to the client side but page is not updated with new data

Comment: Can you show your code, those that you were trying to do ?
That'll be helpful if you want helps.

Comment: @Full.C edited with code an screenshot

Comment: Ok, you should replace the DOM with you new data from you js file.

Comment: Can you give me an example what should I do exactly?

Comment: put this in your $.post ajax request:
.done(function(data){
      $("#id_in_dom").replaceWith($("#id_in_dom",$(data)));
})

Comment: I changed the code per your instruction but there is no effect, this is how the ajax request looks like              $.post(url,{"query" : newValue,csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}).done(function (data) {
                  $("#container").replaceWith("#container",$(data))
              });
What I dont get is why after the post_new function is called it does not re render the page with the new collected data

Comment: Remove the quotes around query. {query:NewValue,....

Answer (score 0):

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'
```

Don't put the csrf like that, {{csrf_token}} means the HTML code.
Put the csrf_token in your template, wherever in your HTML code.

Try to use your ajax request like that instead of what you did:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:{
        query:newValue,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
    },
    success:function(data){
        $("#container").replaceWith($("#container",$(data)));
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still doesnt work :-(, Ill give more data maybe it will provide more clarity. the <div="container"> is a wrapper for a table where all data is populated. before the <tbody> tag I have {% if object_list %} which checks whether this list exists (part of the render function in views file) and if so data is populated. in terms of the post request it goes out well but still the new data is not rendered though I can see it in dev mode in the browser

Comment: Ok, I solved it, under success I place the following statement $("body").html(data);